# Getting a minus one from read call when trying to connect through sql developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I'm getting the following failure message when trying to connect to Oracle database through Oracle SQL Developer.

I was able to connect through command prompt and I unlocked user 'hr'.

Comment: How are you connecting on the command line.  It seems highly unlikely that you configured the Oracle listener to run on port 8080.  The default port is 1521.  8080 would be much more common for a web server like the one that is serving up the database control.

Comment: yes, I changed the port number and SID to 'XE' then it worked!